# Text won't wrap under image in responsive design

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

[Searched but couldn't find an answer ... if this is a duplicate, please point to the other]

I'm having a bit of a problem in getting the text below an image to wrap. I am using a Bootstrap template. I have created the CSS shown below but can't get a line of text longer than the picture to wrap to the next line.

```
.picture {background-color: #F9F9F9;border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;padding: 3px;font: 11px/1.4em Arial, sans-serif;}
.picture img {border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;vertical-align:middle;margin-bottom: 3px;}
.rightPicture {margin: 0.5em 0pt 0.5em 0.8em;float:right; text-align:right;}
.img-responsive,.thumbnail > img,.thumbnail a > img,.carousel-inner > .item > img,.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {display: block;max-width: 100%;height: auto; /* This is from a Bootstrap template */
```

Text/image in question ...

```
<div class="picture rightPicture"><img src="/img/netanyahu-obama-whiteHousegov.jpg" width="400" height="266" class="img-responsive" alt="Netanyahu and Obama at the White House"> Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu and US President Barack Obama meet in the Oval Office. [<cite>Source: White House</cite>]</div>
```

[image: Text wrapping problem]

If I use the code below but it won't resize for responsive use as I have set the width of the div:

```
<div class="picture rightPicture" style="width:402px;"> <img src="/img/netanyahu-obama-whiteHousegov.jpg" width="400" height="266" class="img-responsive" alt="Netanyahu and Obama at the White House"> <br>Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu and US President Barack Obama meet in the Oval Office. [<cite>Source: White House</cite>] </div>
```

Any ideas how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max-width` instead, then the div will scale with the viewport if it's < `402px`

```
<div class="picture rightPicture" style="max-width:402px;"> <img src="/img/netanyahu-obama-whiteHousegov.jpg" width="400" height="266" class="img-responsive" alt="Netanyahu and Obama at the White House"> <br>Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu and US President Barack Obama meet in the Oval Office. [<cite>Source: White House</cite>] </div>
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Lee awesome, you bet :)